# Restkit - Wait for completion and stop all operation if something fails

Tags: restkit, nsoperation

I have a batch of requests that I build as follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)

{
     RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil                                           method:RKRequestMethodPOST                                                                       path:@"sync.json"                                                                          parameters: nil];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
        {

        }
                                         failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        }];
        [objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
}
```

The code is supposed to stop and wait to every single operation before going on.
How can I stop or rather remove all queued operation if something goes wrong?
Maybe by using `cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod`?

**[EDIT]**

In Restkit 0.20 maybe is better to use `objectManager postObject:reqObj`...

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? How did you change the queue configuration?

Comment: I will post my solution sooner...